# What is the best Python Design pattern for consuming Paginated Messages from a TWILIO's HTTP GET REST API response?

Tags: python, pagination, python-requests, twilio, azure-databricks

Trying to implement source_to_raw to consume Twilio API responses via a python script. Below is a sample code I have tried. I hope there should be a better way than this.

I'm exploring options to accomplish via Python helper libraries without any schema options as its only to raw_zone. I ran into infinite loops of never ending 'next_page_uri''s. Twilio offers pageSize limits but couldn't figure out an end of 'page'(s) for designing an exit condition for loops and conditional statements in my code. Any help regarding Twilio Pagination on Python-AzureDatabricks stack would be of great help.

Following is the sample code & a couple of sample responses.

````
page_data = page_response(url,date,creds)
data.update(page_data)
while(page_data['next_page_uri']!=None):
    page_data = page_response(url,date,creds)
    data.update(page_data)
    next_page_url=data['next_page_uri']
    src_url='https://api.twilio.com'
    url=src_url+next_page_url
    print(url)```

Sample Responses:   
#response_0:
{
   "first_page_uri":"",
   "end":11111,
   "previous_page_uri":"/2010-04-01/..../",
   "messages":[{raw...data}]
   "next_page_uri":""/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json?start=2020-12-02PageSize=50&Page=1"
   "page":0
}  
#response_1:
{
   "first_page_uri":"",
   "end":49,
   "previous_page_uri":"",
   "messages":[{raw...data}]
   "next_page_uri":""/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json?start=2020-12-02PageSize=50&Page=2"
   "page":1
}
````

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but you can always do some recursion like the following code:

```
def get_twillo_data(url, date, creds, data):
    _data = page_response(url, date, creds)
    data += _data['messages']
    next_page_uri = _data.get('next_page_uri')
    if next_page_uri:
        get_twillo_data(
            url = url + next_page_uri,
            date = date,
            creds = creds,
            data = data
        )
    else:
        return data

data = []

messages = get_twillo_data(
    url='https://api.twilio.com', 
    date='ur_date', 
    creds='ur_creds', 
    data = data
)
```